# Generating domain model classes from swagger with Autorest

Tags: swagger, autorest

I'm trying to use Autorests own example to generate a client.

https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/main/docs/generate/readme.md

And when I run

`autorest --input-file=pets.json --csharp`

I get a Client class and an Options class. But it does not generate the Dog or Kitten classes for me, eventhough I can see the they are defined the pets.json file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: which version of autorest are you using ? I'm using the last one with java / csharp and all goes in error

Comment: I have installed using Choco
> autorest --version
AutoRest code generation utility [cli version: 3.6.2; node: v18.11.0]

Showing All Installed Exten
 Type       Extension Name                           Version      Location
 core       @autorest/core                           3.9.3        C:\Users\pgp\.autorest\@autorest_core@3.9.3
 extension  @autorest/csharp                         3.0.0-beta.20221019.2 C:\Users\pgp\.autorest\@autorest_csharp@3.0.0-beta.20221019.2
 extension  @autorest/modelerfour                    4.23.7       C:\Users\pgp\.autorest\@autorest_modelerfour@4.23.7

Comment: I think you should open a bug on their's github and ask help from there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autorest --input-file=pets.json --csharp --generation1-convenience-client`

seemed to be the answer :)

Comment: That generated the models for me, but changed the client a lot. I found the client to be a lot harder to work with.